# bash error rspec command not found

Tags: rspec, rubygems

I am a new to ruby/rails and I came across this error in my command line during an assignment:
-bash: rspec: command not found

I received this error after I installed the rspec gem with:
gem install rspec

Here are a few things I have tried:

> -bash: rspec: command not found Jackies-MacBook-Pro:address_bloc jackieturner$ aptitude install libgemplugin-ruby
>
> -bash: aptitude: command not found Jackies-MacBook-Pro:address_bloc jackieturner$ bundle exec rspec Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/
>   directory Jackies-MacBook-Pro:address_bloc jackieturner$ cd ..
>
> Jackies-MacBook-Pro:development jackieturner$ cd ..
>
> Jackies-MacBook-Pro:~ jackieturner$ bundle exec rspec Could not locate
>   Gemfile or .bundle/ directory Jackies-MacBook-Pro:~ jackieturner$

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

looks like you forgot to install rspec and therefore don't have access to it. Just do a quick `gem install rspec` and you should be able to run your tests after that.

Comment: Thank you for the input. That was actually the first thing I did. I apologize for not posting that in my question.